# Angular wait for initial load

Tags: angular

In my angular project, I have the following setup:

I have API to fetch some data from server at the beginning of the app load:

**ItemFetch.ts**

At the beginning of app load, it fetches data from API then changes the `itemLoaded` to true.

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

...
dataLoaded: boolean = false;

dataAPI(){  //Stores in local storage   
 ...
  .then(data=>{
     this.itemLoaded = true;
  })       
 ...
}
```

**main.ts:**

Then, once data is stored, I need to load the stored data only when `itemLoaded` from `ItemFetch.ts` is true.

```
import { dataFromStorage} from './data_from_storage' //local storage

export class main_page {        

constructor(public itemStorage: dataFromStorage){};

ngOnInit(){
   this.fetchInitialData();
}
  //Fetch the data from the storage
  fetchInitialData(){
     this.itemStorage.GetItemDataFromStorage('some_item_id')
      .then((data) => {
          console.log("Got the data!" + data);
      )
  };

}
```

**Question:**

How do I share this `dataLoaded` from one component to another so that I can initiate `this.fetchInitialData();` only when `dataLoaded` is true?

Comment: I would store the variable in a singleton service. This way both components can inject the service and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you find yourself thinking: *"I need code to run but only after X happens"*, you basically need an event handler. In Angular, the easiest way to get that done is with RxJS Observables.

Have a service solely responsible for notifying all interested listeners that the data has arrived.

```
export class LoadNotifierService{
  public dataLoaded : ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject();  
}
```

Provide this service in your `AppModule.providers` array, and inject the service in the component that loads the data, and in any component that needs to know that loading is complete.

**itemFetch**: get data, then raise the event

```
// .next() will cause the ReplaySubject to emit TRUE
loadData().then(e => this.loadNotifier.dataLoaded.next(true));
```

**main**: register an event handler to be notified when the data arrives

```
ngOnInit(){
  // Subscribe will receive notice when the ReplaySubject emits
  // .take(1) guarantees that this will be run only once per ngOnInit()
  this.loadNotifier.dataLoaded.take(1).subscribe(e => this.fetchInitialData())
}
```

You may need to fix a couple of errors (I didn't run the code), but you get the logic I hope.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand your answer and much appreciated. Just a quick question. What does 'ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject();' do?  Thanks!

Comment: It defines `dataLoaded` as a `ReplaySubject` type.  it's an object that makes it easy to notify listeners when something significant occurs via `ReplaySubject.next()`. It also makes it easy to listen for those notifications with `ReplaySubject.subscribe()`

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated! =)